# Redirect to correct location in wildcard prefix in route group using Laravel

Tags: php, redirect, laravel

I have got a prefix of location before a lot of my urls, for example `example.com/london/`

The problem is that when I want to redirect in my controller using the alias, like so:

```
if($validator->fails()) {
     return Redirect::route('register')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

It redirects to `example.com/%7Blocation%7D/register` instead of `example.com/london/register`

Is there an easy fix for this so that it contains the correct location, or will I have to manually put in the location every time I redirect?

My `routes.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{location}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'LocationController@home');

    Route::get('/register', array('as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getRegister'))->before('guest');
    Route::post('/register', array('uses' => 'AuthController@postRegister'))->before('csrf');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{location}` is handled like a normal route parameter, so you can just pass it as second argument:

```
return Redirect::route('register', 'london')->withErrors($validator);
```

Since it is a route parameter you can also retrieve it like one. With `Route::input()`. That means if you want to redirect to a route with same prefix as the current:

```
return Redirect::route('register', Route::input('location'))->withErrors($validator);
```

You might also add a default value: `Route::input('location', 'london')`